# How to get fractional day with strftime

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm trying to print the current time using a format like `2016-11-02.8826` where the part of the decimal is what fraction of the day has expired:

```
9:11 PM = 21:11 = (21+11/60)/24 = 0.8826...
```

I have gotten as far as `now.strftime('%Y-%M-%d.%H.%M')` which prints the hour and minute (`2016-11-02.21.11`) instead of what I want.

Is it possible to do this with a simple `strftime` format string?